# Confusions about grep --include/--exclude options

Tags: bash, grep, cygwin

I have encountered a strange usage with grep --include/--exclude options in Cygwin.
The below 3 commands **output the same result**:

```
1) grep -rl --include \*.c "copyright" ./*
2) grep -rl --include=\*.c "copyright" ./*
3) grep -rl --include=*.c "copyright" ./*
```

Then I checked that the GNU Grep DOC only mentions the "--include=glob" usage,       so I have 2 confusions regarding to above 3 use cases:
1) Why the "=" can be ignored?
2) Why the "*" character need to be "escaped" as I saw in many online solutions?

Hope someone can help me about the confusions, thanks in advance!

Best regards,
cmjauto

Comment: the last one `--include=*.c` does not work to me in `zsh`. Also, I guess POSIX accepts both `--option=value` and `--option value`.

Comment: @fedorqui thank your for your kindly reply, and do you know the reason of the question 2)?

Comment: This is because `*` has an special meaning in Bash: expand to all the elements in the current directory. With `\*` we skip this expansion. For example, say `ls *` and you will see all the elements there; on the contrary, if you say `ls \*` it will try to match a file called `*`.

Comment: @fedorqui, yes, * is a meta character, but if I want to include all the .cpp files under current dir, I will use *.cpp, right? because no file has '*' in its name. Am I understand correctly?
However, the strange thing is that both *.cpp and \*.cpp works on my side.

Comment: Did it match files in the same directory you were in or also in some subdirectories? To make it would make sense that it was just the first, which would be explained by the fact that `*` expanded to all the `.c` files you have in your current dir even before `grep` was executed.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the strange thing is that both *.cpp and *.cpp works on my
>   side.

I take you mean *that both \*.cpp and *.cpp works*. That's because `bash`, when processing the word `--include=*.cpp`, looks for a file with such a name (beginning with `--include=` and ending with `.cpp`), and in default setting if such a file doesn't exist it leaves the word as it is. The same effect of leaving the `*` in place is accomplished by escaping it with `\`, disabling filename expansion.

Of course it's advisable to explicitly escape the `*` character rather than trust to luck that there isn't a filename matching the pattern.